# How to capture a web stream's picture in swift without playing it

Tags: swift, ffmpeg, stream, frame, capture

I am developing an application for ios, using swift in wich I need to capture one frame from the stream at every minute, to show in a picture view.

I am thinking to use ffmpeg.
I tried the ffmpeg command in my mac terminal, and it works:

ffmpeg -probesize 4096 -analyzeduration 50000 -threads 1 -i  -vf fps=fps=1 -frames 1 -threads 1 -y -s 320×240 -f mjpeg -pix_fmt yuvj444p .jpg

But I don't know how to call my compiled ffmpeg for ios, inside my app (I already has compiled it, with the '.a' libs)

I also read about using something like (not ffmpeg):

```
func thumbnail(sourceURL sourceURL:NSURL) -> UIImage?
{
    let asset = AVAsset(URL: sourceURL)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    var time = asset.duration
    time.value = min(time.value, 2)

    do {
        let imageRef = try imageGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
        return nil;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.
it returns this error:

Image generation failed with error Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x15734af0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12782 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12782)}
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please read the full error message, that is until the end.

Comment: Ok, but what is the Optional value? I call the thumbnail func this way: 
            url = NSURL(string: channel.getURL())!
            cell.thumbImageFromUrl.image = thumbnail(sourceURL: url)!;

Comment: Also note that the address exists and can be played by Vlc and my app.

Comment: I'm most certain that you can quickly verify all of your variables. The question will be greatly improved when you find which of the vars is causing the problem or add a note that you've checked all of them and none of them are nil, although at that point you most likely will know yourself the exact reason of the crash and therefore will be able to resolve it and answer the question.

Comment: I think the problem is that, at this statement "var time = asset.duration" the time is indefined (null) because, as it is a stream, it doesn't have an end time. All the examples I have found uses this statement and doesn't work to capture only a frame from a stream m3u8. The idea is to have a thumbnail of what is playing in the channel, at every 10 minutes.

Comment: See, that wasn't hard to find, the problem is solved.

Comment: @A-Live I am also facing the same issue. Have to got any solutions?

Comment: @JagatDave, if you have exactly the same error, author of the post left a comment of what was not working for him. For this kind of (nested) errors you will want to read the full error message, that gives you direction to work on, i.e. check which variable is unwrapped as `nil`. When you find the variable, you can start looking for the reason of why it is `nil`. I can only assume that the snippet worked once unwrapping was fixed, it's up to you to find the exact issue and check it.